# Java - Comparing strings

Tags: java, string, testing, bufferedreader, string-comparison

I am trying to check from a buffered reader if a string value matches user input in browser. If user enters localhost:9999/getMusic data is output fine, however I am trying to make sure that only /getMusic or /getMusic=  is passed and not give a 404 error page ive made. Right now, I can only get 404 if i type /getSomething.

I want it to also give me a 404 if i type for example /getMusicc (with two c's at the end) but it wont give me. I realise its because of the .contains method but I do not know what else to use. Basically I need the exact string value matched to what I have specified. I tried to use .contentsEqual with no luck.

```
String line = reader.readLine();
        if(line !=null){
        System.out.println("[CLIENT] " + soc.getInetAddress().getHostName() 
                + " - " + soc.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " requesting: " + line);

        //the first line should be: GET /path HTTP/1.1
        if (line.startsWith("GET ")&& (line.endsWith("HTTP/1.0")||line.endsWith("HTTP/1.1"))){
            String path = line;//check this

            OutputStream output = soc.getOutputStream();
//here is my problem below...
            if(path.contains("/getMusic") || path.contains("/getMusic=")){
                String type = "";

                if (path.contains("/getMusic=rap")){
                    type = "Rap";
                }
```

I should add that the string is a few words long and the value I want to test is in the middle of all those words. I.E GET /getMusic HTTP1.1. Only /getMusic should be tested.

Working well on first level, however if I wanted to test /getMusic=rap it does not work.

```
  if(path.matches(".*/getMusic=?(\\s+.*)?")){
                String type = "";


                if(path.matches(".*/getMusic=rap")){
                    type = "Rap";
                }
```

Comment: I do not know how to use regex, could you please provide me with an example?

Comment: @GSZingh: See my answer below on using regex to validate the input.

Comment: Check this out http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if(path.contains("/getMusic") || path.contains("/getMusic="))
```

You should use:

```
if(path.matches("^.*?/getMusic=?.*$"))
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is to use regex to test the end of your string. Something like:

```
If(str.matches(".*/getMusic=?$")) {}
```

This will test that anything can appear before the phrase '/getMusic', but nothing can appear after!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`if(path.matches(".*/getMusic=?(\\s+.*)?"))`

Basically what is does are

.* - anything before the string to be tested
/getMusic - you know what this is
=? - to check if "=" optionally exists
(\s+.*)? - if it optionally contains one or more white space + anything after the white space

Comment: Working well on first level, however if I wanted to test /getMusic=rap it does not work.

      if(path.matches(".*/getMusic=?(\\s+.*)?")){
                    String type = "";
                    
                    
                    if(path.matches(".*/getMusic=rap")){
                        type = "Rap";
                    }